# Coding zero values into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working in R with a series of data values that have an x position (distance along a transect) and a z position (distance from the ground for a given x position). There is not a data value measurement at each x, z coordinate, to do the analysis that I need to perform, I need to code a 0 in there. Here is a short code example, real data is usually 14,000-20,000 rows. In Matlab we solve this issue by creating an empty matrix and filling it. I need an x,z matrix normalized to max(z). So in the sample below, max z is 8 and max x is 4, so I need a 4 x 8 matrix where whenever there is no given value present, 0 would be entered--just not sure the best, most efficient way to do this in R.

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
z <- c(1,4,5,6,7,1,4,2,8,1,2,5)
value <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)

data.frame(x,z, value)
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993810/r-selecting-specific-elements-from-a-matrix-all-at-once might be even better as a duplicate, although it assumes more knowledge about R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you would do it much the same way as you describe in Matlab.  First, create a matrix with all zeroes:

```
df <- data.frame(x, z, value)
mat <- matrix(0, 4, 8)
```

And then the tricky part, where you have to create a vector of the selected elements

```
mat[cbind(df$x, df$z)] <- df$value
```

What the cbind is essentially doing is creating a 2-column matrix that is used to identify a set of elements in the matrix, and then assigning the corresponding value.